# S3 Hosting/Query String Authentication broken with extra parameters

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a Django project setup with S3 as the static file host.

`settings.py`

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'project-1'
conn = boto.connect_s3()
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
S3_URL = 'http://project-1.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

And then I make references to static files in my templates using the template tag, like so:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.payment.js' %}"></script>
```

This renders correctly inside the browser, but the URL has 3 other parameters on them, `Signature`, `Expires`, and `AWSAccessKeyId`. The latter two do not have any affect on the file, but accessing the file with the rendered `Signature` value results in an InvalidAccessKeyId error, with the message "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

Manually taking away the `Signature` parameter lets me access the file fine. Taking away all three parameters is fine. Taking away either of the latter two parameters results in an error: "Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters".

[Amazon's S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) reveals that query string authentication is used to allow you access to files that you would normally need authentication to, and that the `Expires` parameter is not, as I thought it was, related to caching. Since it appears that these files don't require any authentication (i.e. I can access them when no URL parameters are present), I need help either:

1. making staticfiles/boto not force these parameters on my urls
2. making staticfiles/boto obtain a valid `Signature` value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`.

Comment: What are the implications?