# Mystery "Signature" and "Expires" parameters being added to Django admin static file URLs

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Django 1.4 webapp using `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` as the file storage backend to serve static files from AWS S3.

Everything works -- except admin static files. On inspection of the admin page source, it's clear the problem is coming from the admin static file URLs, for example for the admin's `base.css` stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://watchdog_staticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/css/base.css?Signature=sFKzAavHHKYdJQVDGTwwSAyrrjc%3D&Expires=1387824617&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAYZSKEJIVD52OCQ" />
```

The problem is the presence of the `Signature`, `Expires`, and `AWSAccessKeyId` URL parameters. With these there, the link leads to an access denied response from AWS. Without them, i.e. just going to the plain URL https://watchdog_staticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/css/base.css, there's no problem (as the file is set to be publicly readable).

These signature/expires/etc parameters are not being added to static URL links in my main webapp, just within the admin.

So my question is -- where are they coming from and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: I guess your front-end uses `{{ STATIC_URL }}`? The admin uses the `{% static %}` template tag, so maybe that's the difference

Comment: @sk1p - you are right! So that means the admin URLs are being generated by `S3BotoStorage` right? Looking into why it would be creating invalid URLs. I've already checked my AWS credentials are correct. I suspect it is the expiration as everything has been working for a long time and then for no reason broke -- consistent with something expiring.

Comment: @sk1p -- Mystery solved. I had my computer's date set to be yesterday (for unrelated reasons) which caused `S3BotoStorage` to generate URLs that were already expired from S3's point of view. Putting the date back to today fixed it. Thanks for the clue that helped me figure this out.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500380/s3-hosting-query-string-authentication-broken-with-extra-parameters